# Telerik Reporting - Columns do not line up

Tags: reporting, telerik, inline

Trying to get columns to line up in Telerik report (Q2 - 2009.) The report was auto-generated by the wizard and the width was increased. I cannot figure out how to get the columns to line up properly. They are rendering all out of whack. I've attached a screenshot to demonstrate.

[Screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/50cd509477.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/50cd509477.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that upgrading to Q3 2009 should fix this problem.